# Javascript debugging mystery

Tags: javascript

I have 2 pretty similar page... the only difference is the images loaded in the array... one work perfectly (rotating picture) the other error all the time :

```
Error: this.img is null
Source File: http://www.fibro.ca/js/blender.js
Line: 54
```

I check out thing.. copy/paste code and do all i can think of... no luck... do somebody have a divine illumination over that problem... ?

page that work : http://www.fibro.ca/html-ang/25-PIS-fiche.php?numero=1

page that error out : http://www.fibro.ca/html-ang/44-SPA-fiche.php?numero=1

Comment: Do you really expect someone debugging your entire site? Try narrowing down the problem and post relevant portions of your javascript and HTML code illustrating the issue.

Comment: just 2 script that contain <20 lines ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not identical "except for the images"

The "page that works" is the one that is throwing the error you mentioned and some some incorrect javascript in it:

```
$("fichephoto").observe("click", function() {

running = !running;

if(running) { blender.start(); }  
else { blender.stop(); }
});

    new Blender("swapphoto", images, {fadeDuration: 1,displayDuration: 1});

    });
```

Whats up with the extra Blender at the end? You are not setting it to a variable, so how would you be using it?

Also, it would help if you did some better indentation,  makes the code a little easier to read.

Comment: You are 50% right... i have remove the extra observer.. but the problem way the problematic html file dont have the ID set for the div container, add id, fixed !

Answer (score 0):

You are missing:

```
new Blender("swapphoto", images, {fadeDuration: 1,displayDuration: 1});
```